# How does one delegate a subdomain of a domain in route53 to a DNS server outside of route53 (i.e. bind)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, bind, amazon-route53

Everything I'm seeing in AWS documentation and SO and web searches seems to be telling me this isn't possible, but I would have sworn I was able to do this a few years ago.

If you have a domain in AWS Route53, can you delegate a subdomain to a DNS server that ISN'T Route53 (such as a bind server on-prem)?

for example, `example.com` is hosted in Route53, and I want the Portland bind server to be authoritative for `portland.example.com`.

In route53, I can create the `NS` record for `portland.example.com` and point that at my bind server, but I can't create an `SOA` record in route53. And if my (admittedly limited) DNS knowledge serves, I need that `SOA` record in the parent domain before the child domain can be considered authoritative. But all I know for sure is that with only an `NS` record, `dig` will not query my Bind server when I search for something like `server.portland.example.com`, it will give me NXDOMAIN, but if I directly query my bind server, it will resolve just fine.

Is this still possible? Was this ever possible? Am I just flubbing my configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was just a network issue and this was working all along.

So the process is:

- In route53, add an `NS` record for your delegated subdomain (i.e. `portland.example.com`), point it at the FQDNs of your delegated Bind servers. An `SOA` record in the parent domain in Route53 is not neccessary.
- In Bind create your zone as normal for the delegated subdomain (`portland.example.com`), with the `NS` and `SOA` records for it.
- If you want your subdomains to be publicly resolvable, ensure that your bind servers are accessible over the Internet by the IP that their FQDN publicly resolve to.